# SendMail IP address change

Tags: linux, sendmail

I have setup a SendMail server and my old SendMail IP address is `1.1.1.2`. I want change it to `2.2.2.3`.

Which file should I edit to make this change?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume you're talking about the host OS's IP, correct? If so, see below, if not, please rephrase your question so it's more clear)

In most configurations, you'll need to set the IP address on the host OS, not specifically in sendmail (though there may be some odd configs out there that require IP address to be hard-coded in sendmail).

Depending on your linux distribution, you'll likely need to change one of these files:

Debian/Ubuntu: `/etc/network/interfaces`

RHEL/Fedora/CentOS: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`